# LinkedList with unwanted zeros

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Ive looked around and I'm not sure if it has been posted or not, but I am trying to create two linked lists in C. When they are supposed to be 'empty' there are zeros. I am not sure where these zeros are coming from and its confusing the hell out of me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int price;
    int bookNumber;

    struct node * next;

};


void addNode(struct node* pHead, int pPrice, int pBookNumber);
void displayList(struct node* pHead);
void removeNode(struct node* pHead, int pBookNumber);

int main()
{

    struct node* head1;
    head1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head1 -> next = NULL;

    addNode(head1, 10, 1234);
    addNode(head1, 35, 9876);
    displayList(head1);
    printf("\n");
    struct node* head2;
    head2 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head2 -> next = NULL;
   // addNode(head2,13, 8888);
    displayList(head2);

}

void addNode(struct node* pHead, int pPrice, int pBookNumber)
{

    struct node* newNode;
    struct node* ptr;

    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode -> price = pPrice;
    newNode -> bookNumber = pBookNumber;

    newNode -> next = NULL;

    ptr = pHead;

    if(pHead -> next == NULL)
    {
        pHead -> next = newNode;
        newNode -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while((ptr -> next != NULL))
        {
            ptr = ptr -> next;
        }

        ptr -> next = newNode;
        newNode -> next = NULL;

    }

}

void removeNode(struct node* pHead,int pBookNumber)
{

    struct node *current, *prev;
    current = pHead;
    /*searching list for the desired data*/
    while((current -> bookNumber != pBookNumber))
    {

        prev = current;

        current = current -> next;

    }

    /*fixing links between nodes*/
    prev -> next = current -> next;

    /*freeing memory*/
    free(current);

    /*removing from end of list*/
    if((current -> next = NULL))
    {

        prev -> next = NULL;

        /*freeing memory*/
        free(current);

    }

}

void displayList(struct node* pHead)
{
        while(pHead != NULL)
        {
            printf("$%d, book# %d -> ", pHead -> price, pHead -> bookNumber);
            pHead = pHead -> next;
        }
        printf("NULL");

    }
```

I added two entries to the first list and didn't add anything to the second list...Here is the output:

```
$0, book# 0 -> $10, book# 1234 -> $35, book# 9876 -> NULL
$0, book# 0 -> NULL
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.001 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Answer (score 2):

the first noticeable problem is that you appear to have a dummy node
in the beginning of the list

```
struct node* head1;
head1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head1 -> next = NULL;
```

but you start printing from `head` not from `head->next` 
ie including dummy node.

Answer (score 0):

`head1` and `head2` are uninitialized nodes which you allocate in `main`. You then add two nodes to `head1` and none to `head2`. You then print the lists from `head1` and `head2`. So they start by printing those uninitialized nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your print loop from the head, and at the very beginning you allocate the memory for your `head1` node. This causes it to print the price and number of the node with unassigned price and book number.

This can be solved by passing a pointer to a pointer `(struct node **pHead)` into your addNode function and adding a check if the head node is `NULL`.

```
newNode -> next = NULL;

ptr = pHead;

if(pHead -> next == NULL)
{
    pHead -> next = newNode;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
}
else
{
    while((ptr -> next != NULL))
    {
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }

    ptr -> next = newNode;
    newNode -> next = NULL;

}
```

This code has another issue here. You are setting the next pointer of newNode to NULL at the start, and then again prior to exiting out of your if-else. This is not necessary, because you are always going to the very end of the list.

```
free(current);

/*removing from end of list*/
if((current -> next = NULL))
{

    prev -> next = NULL;

    /*freeing memory*/
    free(current);

}
```

This code has an issue of freeing the current node, and then I assume you are attempting to check if you are at the very end of the list. However, you are using an assignment operator here. Use `==` for comparison, and were you to attempt removal of nodes, this would cause a segmentation fault, because you are trying to access the memory you had just freed.

Another thing worthy of mention here is that the current->next will be `NULL` in fact, if this is the end of the list, so this check is not even necessary and thus can be removed all together.